# PHP Generate every 2 character combo of the alphabet. Twist: duplicates letters allowed

Tags: php, recursion, permutation

I believe there is something like 67 million combination of two character strings using only the letters of the alphabet.

I basically want an array in PHP containing something like the following

`Array

(

    [1] => AA

    [2] => AB

    [3] => AC

    [4] => AD

    [5] => AE

    [6] => AF

    [7] => AG

    [8] => AH

    [9] => AI

    [10] => AJ

    .... and so on

)`

Comment: I've searched and have been working on this for a couple hours. The twist is that there is allowed duplicates. I can't find or tweak code which would allow this.

Comment: I believe there are exactly 676 combinations.

Comment: @mvds There are indeed 26x26 = 676 combinations :) Branndon, have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with two loop you can do this:

```
<?php 
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C');
foreach ($arr as $value1) {
    foreach ($arr as $value2) {
        echo $value1.$value2;
    }
}
?>
```

Then you can put the result in an array.

Comment: I get a total of 676. I must have done the initial math wrong, but the list looks right! Thanks!