# Find all possible 2 letter combinations in a given string, using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to find all possible 2 letter combinations of a given string.  Is there a faster way to do it, than to apply a substring position by position and then calling the function again?

Below is what I'm trying:

```
function permute($str) {
    if (strlen($str) < 2) {
        return array($str);
    }

    $permutations = array();
    $tail = substr($str, 1);

    foreach (permute($tail) as $permutation) {
        $length = strlen($permutation);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++) {
            $permutations[] = substr($permutation, 0, $i) . $str[0] . substr($permutation, $i);
        }
    }
    return $permutations;
}

$str = "tone";

$permutations = array_unique(permute($str));

$str1 = substr_replace($str, "", 1,2);
$permutations = array_unique(permute($str1));
```

Given the string "tone" above, I'd like to get the answers back:

```
to
tn
te
on
oe
ne
ot
nt
et
no
eo
en
```

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan - That's barely even part of an answer.  How about you round it out a bit more.

Comment: I'm not interested in answering the question. I was just helping you not to do that substr in a foreach!!!

Comment: I didn't know about `str_split()` thanks @mamdouhalramadan!

Comment: @Wayne No, they want anagrams, I don't care how long the string it, I just always want all possible combinations of any 2 characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934490/php-generate-every-2-character-combo-of-the-alphabet-twist-duplicates-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use substr

```
function str2array($string) {
    $strArray = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
        $strArray[] = substr($string, $i, 1);
    }
    return $strArray;
}
```

But use `str_split` instead.

```
$string = 'tone';
$strArray = str_split($string);

foreach ($strArray as $key => $char1) {
    $strArray2 = $strArray;
    unset($strArray2[$key]);
    foreach ($strArray2 as $char2) {
        $permutations[] = $char1 . $char2;
    }
}
//EDIT: adding array_unique in case of dupes
$uniquePermutations=array_unique($permutations);
print_r($uniquePermutations);
```

Array
(
[0] => to
[1] => tn
[2] => te
[3] => ot
[4] => on
[5] => oe
[6] => nt
[7] => no
[8] => ne
[9] => et
[10] => eo
[11] => en
)