# Pair all elements of an array in all possible combinations php

Tags: php, arrays

I've done some searching all i could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624662/find-all-possible-unique-combinations-of-elements-of-an-array-in-php) unfortunately thats not exactly what i'm looking for.

My problem is, i have a list of user ids in an array that could vary in size from 0 to 30+ users.

looks somehting like:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
```

What i need is to be able to find all pairs possible with this users:

```
(1 - 2)
(1 - 3)

(2 - 1)
(2 - 3)

(3 - 1)
(3 - 2)
```

the idea is to be able to create contact lists on a messaging platform so each one has each other on their contact list.

the examples on the question linked above gives me repeating elements and i can't have repeating elements also don't need 3 elements pared together only 2.

Comment: 2 loops, should be easy, tried anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438065/find-all-possible-2-letter-combinations-in-a-given-string-using-php/20438207#20438207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two objectives from the way I see it:

1. Display all possible pairs between *a* and *b* numbers
2. Don't display the same combination twice

[You can achieve this](https://eval.in/398834) with two loops and by keeping track of what you've processed already:

```
$arr = range(1, 30);
$alreadyProcessed = array();

foreach ($arr as $first) {
    // Loop the array twice (as @Dagon mentioned)
    foreach ($arr as $second) {
        // Keep track of what you've already processed
        $combination = array($first, $second);
        // Sorting the numbers will ensure that 2 - 1 and 1 - 2 are the same
        sort($combination);
        // Ensure they aren't the same number and you haven't already processed them
        if ($first === $second || in_array($combination, $alreadyProcessed)) {
            continue;
        }
        // Output as per your example
        echo "($first - $second)" . PHP_EOL;
        // Add it to the list of what you've already processed
        $alreadyProcessed[] = $combination;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** this kind of logic is bad. You're performing an exponential number of repetitions because you're looping an array inside a loop of the same array. This particular example will perform 30 to-the-power-of 30 repetitions (a big, big number of cycles). That's only with 30 entries. What happens if your user base grows to 10,000? Bye bye server.

Comment: @Dagon For people who live in 2015 in other words :)

Comment: Updated for the oldies

Comment: @scrowler Can't we just leave the "oldies" behind, please :)?!

Comment: i know you would not be surprised at just how many servers are not running  5.4.0+  yet (work server number 1 =PHP Version => 5.3.3-7+squeeze26 )

Comment: we just got our last 5.2 server up to 5.4.5 the other day. It was glorious

Comment: @scrowler you have a point there, this is not really practical when numbers are too big... do you have a better solution for this? my initial ideal was to pair users that signup on the past 90 days.

Comment: If you want to pair all users by default then why not make it work the opposite way, as in "blacklist" users if a record/match exists?