# Concatenate a string with a list of strings in PHP

Tags: php

I have an list of strings as follow:

AA
AB
AC
AD ..

I want to append a specific number to each of my elements from this array. What I want the output to be is

AA12345678
AB12345678 ..

You get the idea. I am a total noob so forgive me. I have tried many codes but I haven't managed to work it out.

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions, if the suffix is always the same, could be as follow:

```
$a = ['AA','AB', 'AC'];
$suffix = 12345678;

$b = array_map(function($v) use ($suffix) {
    return $v . $suffix;
}, $a);

var_dump($b);
```

Please see [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) documentation.

Comment: is there any way to print the output as plain text? without the array [0] ... and so on

Comment: Of course. Join my solution with jgoday solution. It will be `echo implode($b)`. If you want a line break between them, use either `echo implode(PHP_EOL, $b)` or `echo implode('<br>', $b)` (if you're printing HTML).

Comment: this worked! I have not created my array of elements, how do I put all the strings (676) into an array?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get your question. What do you need to put into an array? Permutations of the alphabet letters?

Comment: yes, I have generated all 2 letter combinations of alphabet letters (AA, BB .. and so on), but they are in plain text and with a line break. How do I put them into an array? Or is there a way I can generate all combinations and append the desired string?

Comment: Well, it's a completely different problem that stated in the question. I guess you've created something like the second list from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:List_of_two-letter_combinations, correct? If so, just wrap all pair in a quote, separate them with colon and wrap everything with square brackets (if using PHP 5.4+). Otherwise, you need to look for the algorihm (but I don't think it's worth it) - like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438065/find-all-possible-2-letter-combinations-in-a-given-string-using-php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [implode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) function

```
$str = implode('12345', $values);
```

Comment: how do I add a line break between each output?

Comment: implode('12345', array_map(function($v) { return $v . '\n'; }, $values);

Comment: I'm afraid this solution will omit the last element's suffix (the "glue" is between elements, not after all of them).